# Complex roots of unity: Proof

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Corollary 5 The conjugate of a unit root is also a unit root.

Proof From the property of complex numbers

${\displaystyle z\cdot {\overline {z}}=|z|^{2}} {\displaystyle z\cdot {\overline {z}}=|z|^{2}}\:\text{ and }\:{\displaystyle |\epsilon _{k}|=1} {\displaystyle |\epsilon _{k}|=1}, {\displaystyle {\overline {\epsilon _{k}}}={\frac {|\epsilon _{k}|^{2}}{\epsilon _{k}}}={\frac {1}{\epsilon _{k}}}=\epsilon _{-k}=\epsilon _{n-k}} {\displaystyle {\overline {\epsilon _{k}}}={\frac {|\epsilon _{k}|^{2}}{\epsilon _{k}}}={\frac {1}{\epsilon _{k}}}=\epsilon _{-k}=\epsilon _{n-k}}$

Can someone explain how  $\epsilon _{-k}=\epsilon _{n-k}$

Comment: What is $\epsilon_k$?

Comment: who's $\epsilon_k$? where does it come from?

Comment: $\epsilon_k$ is the k-th unit root of order $n$, although this is indeed not articulated and should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1:  "$n-k$": go all the way around the unit circle, then back up by $k$.  "$-k$" : just back up by $k$.

Answer 2: $\epsilon_{n-k} = \epsilon_n \epsilon_{-k} = 1 \epsilon_{-k} = \epsilon_{-k}$.

These two answers say exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric